# Polymer Slide Up Animation in Neon Animated Pages

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, web-animations

Im trying to add animation to neon-animated-pages like so:

```
<neon-animated-pages animate-initial-selection="true" entry-animation="slide-up-animation" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
    <neon-animatable data-route="home">
        <home-page></home-page>
    </neon-animatable> 
</neon-animated-pages>
```

This works fine if i change the slide-up-animation to scale-up for example. Every other animation works except this the slide-up-animation.

I have included the animation itself, and any other i tryed. My neon-animation elements are version 1.0.8

Is this a polymer bug, or do i have to do something different when using slide-up-animation?